# How to generate PPT in laravel in windows Os?

Tags: laravel, powerpoint

i am generating Powerpoint from my database.It works fine on ubuntu but doesnot display on windows.Only blank ppt is shown .In windows blank ppt is generated.my code is

// Create slide

```
    $currentSlide = $objPHPPowerPoint->getActiveSlide();
```

// Create a shape (drawing)

```
    $shape = $currentSlide->createDrawingShape();
    $shape->setName('PHPPresentation logo')
        ->setDescription('PHPPresentation logo')
        ->setPath(base_path().'/public/images/pp_bg.jpg')
        ->setHeight(36)
        ->setOffsetX(10)
        ->setOffsetY(10);
    $shape->getShadow()->setVisible(true)
        ->setDirection(45)
        ->setDistance(10);
```

// Create a shape (text)

```
    $shape = $currentSlide->createRichTextShape()
        ->setHeight(300)
        ->setWidth(600)
        ->setOffsetX(170)
        ->setOffsetY(180);
    $shape->getActiveParagraph()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal( Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER );
    $textRun = $shape->createTextRun('Thank you for using PHPPresentation!');
    $textRun->getFont()->setBold(true)
        ->setSize(60)
        ->setColor( new Color( 'FFE06B20' ) );



    // generate PPT file.
    $oWriterPPTX = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPPowerPoint, 'PowerPoint2007');
    $oWriterPPTX->save("Proposal $id.ppt");
    $file_url = "Proposal $id.ppt";
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_url));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' .filesize($file_url));

    readfile($file_url);
```

Comment: Any error while create PPT with Win OS?

Comment: no error but in ppt slide there is no data ,it is blank but in ubuntu it works fine

Comment: You mean that 'while you open same PPT with winOS, it's blank"?

Comment: yes its blank and while opening it says powerpoint was unable to display some of the text,images or objects on slide in the file proposal.ppt.because they have become corrupted.affected slides have replaced by blank slides inthe presentation and it is not possible to recover the lost information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but this is may be issue with you are using font's are not exist/installed into your WinOS system. Try with support font(Your both ubuntu + WinOs). You can read more [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation#features) about PHPPresentation
 package feature.

Helpful link: [Slides show up blank (white) when opening presentation in Powerpoint for Mac 2011](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_mac/slides-show-up-blank-white-when-opening/312fd117-2265-4499-bcc6-7b98fa4c2933)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thankyou sir for your Response but still problem is not solved

Comment: using PhpPresentation package in laravel  how can we save file  as microsoft powerpoint 97-2003..this will solve my  problem.

Comment: Problem fixed by using OdpPresentation instead of powerpoint 2007

Comment: @BikashBudhathoki: Enjoy